# WPBakery Visual Composer not loading

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer, wordpress-gutenberg

Im using the latest Wordpress version. Since GUTENBERG the Visual Composer is not working. I installed Classic Editor plugin. But it brought nothing. Also the Theme Customizer is not loading.

Here you will find the error messages from the Console:

[image]

[image]

Theme: ColorMag

Comment: I know it sounds silly, but have you tried uninstalling Visual Composer and installing it again now that the Classic Editor has been installed?

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade PHP limits like below:

- max_execution_time 300
- memory_limit 256M
- post_max_size 32M
- upload_max_filesize 32M

Also, updating the WP Bakery plugin should solve the problem as the plugin developers added to disable the Gutenberg editor on version 5.6 
https://kb.wpbakery.com/docs/preface/release-notes/

Answer (score 0):

If u've got problems with visual comopser is almost always blame of php version or max characters:

1. Check compatibility of your visual composer with php version at your server using link below:
   https://kb.wpbakery.com/docs/preface/release-notes/
2. Check what php version u use at server
3. Check your visual composer version in ur installed plugin list
4. If everything should be compatible than do -> set max_input_vars = 10000 in php.ini or ask your hosting provider
   to increase the limit

   5. Wordpress and theme update is also good idea.

Ps. To check your php version you can just write phpinfo() in your page template.